# ExtJs 4 Combobox multiselect issue

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I am using ExtJs combobox with multiselect set to true.

Issue - Suppose I am having a combobox with 10 city names where multiselect is allowed.

Page - 1 : I am allowing the user to select multiple cities and save into the database what he has selected.(Suppose city1,city2 are selected)

Page - 2 : Here on this page i giving the user an edit functionality to the user to edit the information, so now here i need to show the combobox populated(selected) with previous values.
That I am doing with following code -

```
combo.setValues(arrayOfPrevValues);
```

So this allows me to show prev selected values into the combobox i.e. city1 and city2 are selected. Now when the user starts editing the information for the city then the previous selected values are lost from the combobox.

Can some one help me out finding what is going wrong over here or do i need to do something inside combo config.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am assuming that you want old values as well as new values.

So,I suggest you to override the change event in the combobox config.

just append the following snippet to the config

```
listeners: {
      change: function (cb, newValue, oldValue, options) {
          //do some thing with the old and new value
          console.log(newValue, oldValue);
      }
    }
```